# Numerics.Matrix4x4 behavior

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm using a MS library System.Numerics and a function called Matrix4x4.CreateLookAt(V3 pos, V3 target, V3 up)

I'm constructing target from *position + forward*.

As far as I can tell, the function incorrectly inverts the forward vector. So if I give it a forward vector <0,0,1> the matrix internally represents the forward vector as <0,0,-1> and this is justified by this statement...

> They are functionally similar but with f being inversed. That is:

> in left-handed you do *target - position*

> in right-handed you do *position - target*

As far as I know, changing the orientation of the space between LH and RH doesn't change the basic vector maths, and so my question..

Does *target - position* always give direction vector (from position to target), in both LH and RH systems?

Edit: If it's helpful, you can see my post here... https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/74805 which shows my understanding of the view matrix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify, I've given all the information I have. The question stands as stated 'Does target - position always give direction vector (from position to target), in both LH and RH systems?' The problem is... my knowledge of these systems and how they are implemented in software is limited, and I don't understand why a vendor would reverse the equation for target. I can only assume that they have done something funky down the line, and it makes sense in that context.